# Creating and injecting SQL query into DAL

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to write a DAL to do mapping on input model, data normalization and some other encryption tasks at low-levels of my app, and i want to limit my SQL queries to run only through DAL.
i changed my dbContext to private to achieve last one. 
but in order to pass queries to DAL, i need to a way of building and passing all types of SQL queries that i could inject them into DAL and then run final query against main EntityModels.

for example i tried this way without any result:

Main.cs:

```
IEnumerable<DataAccess.Model.Group> Output = new List<DataAccess.Model.Group>();
Output = from A in Output.Where(P => P.Name.StartsWith("A")) select A;
Group.FakeSelect(Output);
```

and in my DAL i tried something like it:

```
public List<Group> FakeSelect(IEnumerable<Group> Query, out List<NewGroup> NewModel)
{
    IQueryable<Group> Source = GetQuery();
    Query = Query.Union(Source);
    return (from A in Query select new NewGroup{....}).ToList();
}
```

Im using this function to get main entityModel query :

```
public IQueryable<DataAccess.Model.Group> GetQuery()
{
        ShamsEntities Entities = new ShamsEntities();
        return Entities.Set<DataAccess.Model.Group>();
}
```

I expected to see all rows with Names that startwith("A") but the result was whole table's rows.

Comment: You are abusing your DAL (_it_ should do the queries, not your BLL), you are calling a non-static without an instance and without the required out-parameter (which won't even compile) and you are ignoring whatever that method returns, making it very hard to understand where you get a result at all. Please try to rephrase your question to be more clear about what you want to achieve, and check the code you posted - it should at the very least compile.

Comment: If `from A in Output.Where(P => P.Name.StartsWith("A")) select A;` is the "query" you expect top be sending to `FakeQuery`: it is not. `Output` is simply an `IEnumerable<Group>`, and certainly _not_ a query (or, what you are looking for, an _expression_)

Comment: I have read some n-tier implementation and i saw that i'm trying to force something like Persistent-Layer works in DAL. 
i'm using Expressions now, but i needed to provide all SQL command types (e.g Group By, Having, IN, Joins, ....)
after some answers in Stackoverflow i was satisfied that i must leave this task's to upper layers and i must have some other issues in this layer.

Answer (score 3):

If you pass SQL queries in to your DAL from another layer - then it isn't your DAL, as SQL is inherantly "DA (Data Access)" and so should only live in the DAL. You probably want to either create a method for each type of query, pass a Filter type object, or maybe an expression object to your DAL, which can then parse and run the relevant SQL. Otherwise, if you want to swap out your Data Access method, for example using XML files instead of a database - you will have to change all your code, not just your DAL, defeating the point in seperating it out into a different layer in the first place!

P.S. Encryption probably shouldn't be the responsibility of the DAL...

---

**Edit: This paragraph from the article you linked explains what i mean:**

> Encapsulate data access functionality within the data access layer.
>   The data access layer should hide the details of data source access.
>   It should be responsible for managing connections, generating queries,
>   and mapping application entities to data source structures. Consumers
>   of the data access layer interact through abstract interfaces using
>   application entities such as custom objects, TypedDataSets, and XML,
>   and should have no knowledge of the internal details of the data
>   access layer. Separating concerns in this way assists in application
>   development and maintenance.

Comment: I read below article before implementation, and i have thought that would be great to get ride of Mapping models and some other tasks at business layer. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658127.aspx
so, what should i put in my DAL ?
thanks

Comment: DAL should contain Data Access Code... as in, the code that interacts with your persistant storage (in this case a database). Therefore ANYTHING related to the database goes here, and nothing else. This means if you decide to not use a database in future, this layer is the ONLY code that should need changed, and everything else continues working in exactly the same manner. I suggested 3 different methods of letting the DAL know which queries you want it to run, there are certainly more, but do not pass SQL from antoher layer to this layer, as SQL belongs only inside this layer.

Comment: Added a quote from the exact article you linked that is reffering to what I mean, it seems to agree

Answer (score -2):

Writing queries is a business logic concern, not a DAL concern.  Which entities are needed, how they are shaped and sorted are details of a business logic method, or transaction script.  If you are in the middle of writing a bit of business logic and need to jump over to your DAL to implement a new method that returns the data you need, you are mixing concerns.

The DAL should hide the details of the repository used, and so LINQ was invented so the queries could be expressed in a repository-agnostic way, and in the language of the business logic layer.

LINQ also enables query composition and deferred execution, and so the intended, and recommended way to interact with a LINQ-enabled repository or DAL (like an EF DbContext) is for the business logic layer to start with an IQueryable property, and build up a custom query.

Comment: So what should be in the DAL than? Just the EF model and nothing else?

Comment: The Entity Model isn't really part of the DAL.  The EF DbContext is.  And it's sometimes useful to have interfaces that define repository, and have the EF DbContext be one implementation.  And you will often add custom methods to the DbContext, especially if following the CQRS pattern, which makes data mutation a DAL concern, while leaving query as a business logic concern.

Comment: For the record, I did not down vote this... So in this approach the Entity Model would still be in the DAL in order to get access to DbContext but what you are saying is that it's not really part of the DAL? Do you perhaps know of an open source or sample solution that would demonstrate this approach well?

Comment: The OOB EF Code First From Existing Database demonstrates this.  The Entities are created based on the database tables, and mapped back to them with Attributes or FluentAPI.  But other than the mapping attributes the Entities don't depend on the DbContext.